Avoid new page after end a section in latex
I am working on latex, and this is my main.tex, including all the packages which will be used:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcounter{Chapcounter}
\newcommand\showmycounter{\addtocounter{Chapcounter}{1}\themycounter}
\newcommand{\chapter}[1] 
{ {\centering          
  \addtocounter{Chapcounter}{1} \Large {\textbf{ \color{black} Chapter \theChapcounter: ~#1}} }   
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ \color{black} Chapter:~\theChapcounter~~ #1}    
}

%\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\usepackage{header}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amssymb,epsfig,latexsym,multicol,array,hhline,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}
}

\lstdefinestyle{myverbatim}{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, % if you need to escape LaTeX code within verbatim
    postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\hookrightarrow$}\space}
}


\begin{document}

\input{Sections/0.Cover_Page}
\include{Sections/1.Data_Introduction}
\include{Sections/2.Background}
\include{Sections/3.Data_pre-processing}
\include{Sections/4.Descriptive_statistics}
\include{Sections/5.Inferential_statistics}
\include{Sections/6.Discussion}
\include{Sections/7.Code}
\include{Sections/8.Ref}

\end{document}

My problem is after done 1 section and start new one, there will always have a pagebreak between them, i have used \nopagebreak but it still not work. I also have checked is there any \renewcommand can be lead to the pagebreak (actually i am not sure about this). Is there any way to avoid the pagebreak in my case?
Thank you so much for the reply.

It worked, thank you so much !!

apart from \include why use article then define \chapter by hand, rather than using report that defines \chapter?, don't load color as you load xcolor, don't load epsfig, you load these twice multicol, graphics, array
